# AudioKit 4.9.5 AKRotaryKnobStyle Identifier Name Violation

Tags: swift, audiokit

I've been out of the AudioKit loop for nearly a year so I thought I should update my app with the latest release build, AudioKit 4.9.5 released 11 days ago.

As usual, the first step I take with any new release is to build the frameworks that I use.  After opening a Terminal window and cd'ing to AudioKit-4.9.5/Frameworks I execute this command:

PLATFORMS="iOS macOS" ./build_frameworks.sh

This is the result:

```
❌  /Users/xxxx/Work/AudioKit-4.9.5/AudioKit/iOS/AudioKit/User Interface/AKRotaryKnob.swift:17:10: Identifier Name Violation: Enum element name should only contain alphanumeric characters: 'polygon(numberOfSides:curvature:)' (identifier_name)

/Users/xxxx/Work/AudioKit-4.9.5/AudioKit/iOS/AudioKit/User Interface/AKRotaryKnob.swift:413: warning: File Line Length Violation: File should contain 400 lines or less: currently contains 413 (file_length)
                  ~~~~~~~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


** BUILD FAILED **
```

My environment is:

```
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
macOS 10.15.3 
Xcode Version 11.4
Swift version 5.2
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to update to the latest version of SwiftLint.  Doh!

```
https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases/
```